# html5 local storage value

Tags: html, local-storage

Say I have the following for storing in a localstorage

```
    var storageObject = {}; 
    storageObject.value = myvalue; 
    storageObject.timestamp = d.getTime(); 
    localStorage.setItem(myref, JSON.stringify(storageObject));
```

How do I use the getItem to retreive the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply:

```
localStorage.getItem(myref);
```

Or even:

```
localStorage[myref];
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage

Edit to restore original object from JSON, simply `parse` it:

```
var revivedObject = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem(myref) ); 
// console.log(revivedObject);
```

Comment: but I am storing timestamp and value in storageObject. I need only the value not the timestamp. I did somethign like var myObj = localStorage[datobj];
myObj1 = JSON.parse(myObj.value); but did not work.

Comment: after you *get* value, you will need to `JSON.parse` it to turn it to object again.